# PuppeteerSharp version 3.0.0 - Cannot Load Assembly at Runtime

Tags: puppeteer-sharp

After upgrading to PuppeteerSharp version 3.0, we get the following runtime exception:

Could not load file or assembly 'PuppeteerSharp' or one of its dependencies. **Strong name signature could not be verified**. The assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not fully signed with the correct private key.

Comment: I'm shipping pptr# 4 next week with that fixed up!

Comment: Can you try v4?

Comment: v4 installed and could no longer duplicate the issue. Thanks!